# How does maven deploy snapshot without dependencies with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am using mvn `release-plugin` and `assembly-plugin` to deploy jar with dependency.  It works fine, when I use it with `mvn release`. It creates two files: normal `XXX.jar` and `XXX.jar-with-dependencies.jar` and deploys them both.
But I need also deploy snapshot to another repository by using `mvn deploy`. In this repository I only need the XXX.jar without dependencies. 
So I hope that I could use `mvn deploy` to deploy snapshot version without dependencies with followed setting.

POM.xml setting:

```
        ...
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>install</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

PS: `mvn clean install deploy` will be called by jenkins `scm pulling` schedule every morning.

Comment: The execution of `clean install deploy` does not make sense and shows that you don't understand the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). The call `clean deploy` is sufficient.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: Thank you for your information. I corrected it as `mvn clean deploy`.

Comment: For some reason of confidentiality, I can't show the full pom file. With the showed the setting (assembly plugin) in pom.xml, it will automatically create two jars and deploy them both by using `mvn deploy`. My Question is, how to deploy only the normal jar file with `mvn deploy` and deploy both jar and jar with dependencies by using `mvn release:prepare release:perform`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifacts produced by `maven-assmbly-plugin` are automatically attached to the project and hence are deployed when you call `mvn deploy`. 
What you can do is to define a profile (say 'with-dependencies') where you put the assembly plugin execution. In this case if you call `mvn deploy` it will build a -SNAPSHOT version and push it to the snapshot repository and for the release you will have to call `mvn release:prepare release:perform -Pwith-dependencies`

```
<profile>
  <id>with-dependencies</id>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
          <phase>install</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</profile>
```